# Chrome-Extension HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating this Chrome-Extension, which when you click a button on the current page, launches a new HTML page with some input fields the user has to complete. The button is being triggered inside the content.js. I was wondering what would be the best/easiest way to retrieve the information the user has input in the HTML form back to the content script/ or override the localStorage variables to be available in the content script after the submit button in the form has been pressed. Any thoughts would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Without the code your question is likely to be downvoted or closed. However based on what I've guessed the best method would be using `chrome.storage.local`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have no code, this is purely guessing.
Even so, I think `chrome.storage.local` would be useful.

Here's an example from Google's Website:

```
  function saveChanges() {
    // You'd get a value from your form here.
    var theValue = textarea.value;
    // CCheck there's actually something there
    if (!theValue) {
      message('ERROR - There's nothing here');
      return;
    }
    // Now use the Chrome Storage API to save the settings
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
      // Success! Let's log a message.
      message('Settings saved');
    });
  }
```

If you need more help, [check out the info page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: so if I save use the local storage inside the popup html page, will it be preserved inside the content.js?

Comment: @MarcZaharescu Yep, in my experience that's always worked.